# need help with flash gallery and xml file

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

i have xml file that looks like this

```
<image path="test.jpg"/>
```

i need my xml to look like this

```
<image>test.jpg</image>
```

what do i have to change in my flash script

```
attachMovie("Slideshow", "mySlideshow", 1);
mySlideshow.xmlPath = "images.xml";
mySlideshow.setSize(960, 560);
mySlideshow._x = 0;
mySlideshow._y = 0;
mySlideshow.setBorder = true;
mySlideshow.borderThickness = 5;
mySlideshow.preloaderType = "circular";
mySlideshow.transitionEffect = "squares";
mySlideshow.squaresEffectType = "blur";
mySlideshow.squaresDirection = "random";

attachMovie("ThumbnailScroller", "myScroller", 2);
myScroller.xmlPath = "thumbnails.xml";
myScroller.setSize(500, 70);
myScroller._x = 34;
myScroller._y = 307;
myScroller.setBorder = true;
myScroller.borderThickness = 3;
myScroller.easingType = "Back";
myScroller.easingMethod = "easeInOut";
myScroller.moveAmount = 200;

attachMovie("Arrow", "left", 3);
left._x = myScroller._x - left._width - 5;
left._y = myScroller._y + (myScroller._height - left._height)/2;

attachMovie("Arrow", "right", 4);
right._rotation = 180;
right._x = myScroller._x + myScroller._width + right._width + 5;
right._y = left._y + right._height;

left.onRelease = function(){
    myScroller.moveLeft();
}
right.onRelease = function(){
    myScroller.moveRight();
}

var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.release = function(event:Object){
    mySlideshow.loadImage(event.target.id);
}
myScroller.addEventListener("release", obj);
```

and how to make it work on one image for Slideshow & ThumbnailScroller

thank you all for help

Comment: myScroller seems to be a separate class from what you're working with. Your code doesn't actually parse any XML data, it just pushes the path to your XML file into your myScroller class instance, which then would probably parse the XML. You should dig around inside of the myScroller class and see how it deals with your XML data first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using two external components , could you provide a link to them , and if you already generated you xml and now you want to change them try to find advanced text find and replace with expression support , and change your xmls to standard format which your component support !

are you using this http://flashotaku.com/blog/yet-another-image-gallery/ !?

if yes you can't resource this component legally to deal with your problem as i said try change your xml files to standard ones for this component even you can find many good xml generator which u can define your xml format and give it your image folder , automatically with no pain build your xml files